# How to remove first chracter from the string and store the same into new column in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column name called Student name and each row has four or five student names -- like this John mills, Tim Harry, Alex win, Kate marry... I want to take the first two student names and store into a new column called Student 1 and Student 2. Names have been separated from comma.

I created a function and i can able to extract first student name . result storing into my dataframe called student_0

```
def find_student(df2): 
for i in range(2): 
df2[f"student name_{i}"] = [x.split(',')[i] for x in df2["student name"]] 
return df2
```

```
new_df = find_student(df2)
```

df2 is my dataframe name

I AM NOT GETTING SECOND STUDENT NAME. PLEASE ADVISE

Comment: Can you post a sample of `df2["Actors"] `

Comment: Sorry Rakesh.. That is Student name not Actors. Typo error. Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: Ok a sample of `df2["student name"] `

Comment: Student name
1) John mills, Tim Harry, Alex win, Kate marry
2) Brando XI, James Caan, Richard S. Castellano
3) Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select first 2 columns by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if need name and surnames:

```
print (df2)
                                   student name
0   John mills, Tim Harry, Alex win, Kate marry
1  Brando XI, James Caan, Richard S. Castellano
2   Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine 

N = 2
df3 = df2["student name"].str.split(', ', expand=True).iloc[:, :N]
#rename columns names
df3.columns = [f"student name_{i+1}" for i in range(len(df3.columns))]
print (df3)
  student name_1 student name_2
0     John mills      Tim Harry
1      Brando XI     James Caan
2   Heath Ledger  Aaron Eckhart
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
N = 2
L = [x.split(',')[:2] for x in df2["student name"]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=[f"student name_{i+1}" for i in range(N)])
print (df3)
  student name_1  student name_2
0     John mills       Tim Harry
1      Brando XI      James Caan
2   Heath Ledger   Aaron Eckhart
```

If need only names:

```
N = 2
L = [[y.split()[0] for y in x.split(',')[:2]] for x in df2["student name"]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=[f"student name_{i+1}" for i in range(N)])
print (df3)
  student name_1 student name_2
0           John            Tim
1         Brando          James
2          Heath          Aaron
```

---

```
#join to original if necessary
df2 = df2.join(df3)
```

Comment: u there online?

Comment: @Jason Sorry, 4 days offline, on phone only.

Comment: Hi, u there today?

Comment: @Jason - yes, I am

Comment: I have a dataframe which types are object. I want to convert into float. I made a user defined function                                                                                                   def convert(x):
    x = x.astype(str).astype(float)
    return x....                    Pass it to churn.iloc[:, 6:20] = churn.iloc[:, 6:20].apply(convert).. I am not getting error, But object types are not changng into flotat. can you please advise?

Comment: NO it is not working.. it  is not converting into float. But I am also not getting error

Comment: when I check the dtypes of the dataframe.. all the variables are showing object only.. any suggestions what went wrong here..

Comment: @Jason - i have no sample data, so not easy find solution.

Comment: Can I send email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195494/discussion-between-jason-and-jezrael).

Comment: Hi u there today?

Comment: R u available today?

Comment: are you available?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def find_student(df2): 
    for i in range(2): 
        df2[f"student name_{i}"] = pd.Series(map(lambda x: x.split(',')[i], df2["student name"]))
return df2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas functionality(str and split), you don't need to write a function.

```py
df = [["John mills, Tim Harry, Alex win, Kate marry"],
      ["Brando XI, James Caan, Richard S. Castellano"],
      ["Heath Ledger,Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine"]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df2.columns = ['Student_Name']

df2['student name_1'] = df2.Student_Name.str.split(",").str[0]
df2['student name_2'] = df2.Student_Name.str.split(",").str[1]
```